# Array For Loop causes Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I am having an issue looping through multiple arrays on my Google Maps API Project.

I have a category array inside the markers array and I want to be able to sort through them based on what was selected in the dropdown/select menu from the user.

when they select a value, the following function runs:

```
filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        console.log(marker.category);
        for(i = 0; i < marker.category.length; i++) {
          // If is same category or category not picked
          if (marker.category[i] == category || category.length === 0) {
              marker.setVisible(true);
          }
          // Categories don't match 
          else {
              marker.setVisible(false);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

but instead of comparing each item inside the array to what was selected, it just keeps looping.

**JS Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/japaneselanguagefriend/t3xaj1j5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same global counter (`i`) in two different loops.

JS uses function-level scoping for `var` declarations, but will allow you to use a variable without declaring it for legacy reasons. Both of your loops use `i` without declaring it, so you're working with a single global variable.

In ES5, you can fix that by declaring the counters in both loops and changing one to use another variable, like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < bar; ++j) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The latest language revision adds block-scoped variables, but since your loops are nested, you still need different names:

```
for (let i = 0; i < foo; ++i) {
  for (let j = 0; j < bar; ++j) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Either way, make sure you declare your variables (with `var` or `let`, depending on the language level available) so they don't leak into the global scope. You should have a [`"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) at the head of your script, which will prevent global/undeclared variables across the board.